# What is the correct way of tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits

Browsing through the questions on SO, I noticed the [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) tag and saw hundreds of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartz) that should be retagged. It is also mentioned in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012

What should be the proper way for replacing these tags, I found it a little bit disturbing editing the question and adding a "removed batch added xyz" type of comment.

Is this is a good behavior? I wonder if bulk updates of these kinds are welcomed by the community or they are seen as reputation hunting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the tag needs to be removed or disambiguated, it's okay to suggest edits to posts just to remove the tag.  However, please look for anything else you can do to improve each post you edit.  Bulk updates are welcome, but they will be looked upon as reputation hunting if you pass up a lot of obvious improvements and only change the tag.  People are likely to reject suggested edits if they see a lot of capitalization, spelling, and formatting errors on posts where you only changed one thing.