# Should the [patterns] tag be disambiguated or cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I have noticed that the the [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) tag is full of irrelevant and/or ambiguous questions. At least, the following meanings of "pattern" revealed:

- [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns)
- patterns of [refactoring](/questions/tagged/refactoring)
- [match](/questions/tagged/match), [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), and [pattern-matching](/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) (these three are yet another problem)
- or sometimes they just mean "best practices how to accomplish a certain task" ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073956/best-pattern-to-build-an-api-for-conversion-between-any-two-types-of-tabular-dat))

My observation is that many of the questions already tagged with the proper tags, but *also* incorrectly tagged [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns).

I'm aware about [how to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140392/what-is-the-correct-way-of-tag-cleanup) cleanup tags, but I'm curious about whether it makes any sense retagging more than 800 questions.
Is there any relevant discussion here on Meta?
Does it make any sense re-tagging all questions and removing the tag?

Comment: @casperOne I was surprised myself it did not appear in a http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142385/what-happened-with-great-stack-overflow-tag-cleanup-of-2012

Comment: You mean in the post that post points to.  There's a gajillion tags on SO.  Can't catch em all, even if you are Ash.

Comment: Did someone just merge `pattern` into `design-patterns`? WTF?

Comment: I see now.  `patterns` is a synonym of `design-patterns` (\*shakes head\*) while `pattern` is not.  I would say `patterns` should be broken off from `design-patterns` but first things first.

Comment: patterns has 800 matches so I assumed patterns was meant and not pattern,

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe: Exactly. [pattern] is a synonym, so I guess it's a smaller trouble. **UPD** Thank you for the edit, my fault I failed to spell it correctly.

Comment: I already killed the easy ones, so its 784 now.

Comment: By the way,  would be nice if [pattern-*] worked in search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, the question has a sufficient number of tags to classify it, then the tag removal should not harm it.

However, it doesn't hurt to introduce *new* tags in a situation where it would help classify the question *even better*.

It's ok to clean up a tag of *any* size that's become ambiguous.  In this case, I agree that [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) is totally ambiguous.  It should go, but it should be done in such a way that doesn't make the question harder to find (does it have "pattern" in the title, that's generally just as good as a tag), or makes the tagging on the question *better*.

As always if something is close or deletion fodder, please vote to close/delete and possibly flag for moderator attention where appropriate.  No point in retagging if it's just going to be deleted.

Comment: [pattern] is a synonym, it's easy to remove. But [patterns] can't be deleted at once because not all Q's (but many) have proper tags as well. Also, I'm not clear how to choose between [match], [regex], and [pattern-matching]. To me, they appear almost identical, but it may not be true for environments I'm not aware about. Can you please elaborate?